# Input value returns an empty string due to input font-size="0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input

I found a problem which has bothered me for several weeks. I am using jQuery to retrieve the input text. The user enters some characters and hits ENTER, and I print the text in console.

html:

```
<input id="abc" type="text" autofocus style="font-size:0;">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#abc', function(e) {
  if (e.which!=13) { 
    return;
  }
  console.log('Entered: ' + $('#abc').val());
  $('#abc').val('');
});
```

If I use Firefox, everything is fine. However, if I use Chrome or Opera, they will return a empty string.

I finally found out that the problem comes from `font-size="0"` (I want to hide the input). If the value is anything other than 0, Chrome and Opera will have no problem picking up the entered text.

Questions:

1. Why is that?
2. How do I hide the `<input>` element and it can still take user inputs?

Comment: Curious, why are you hiding the input? How is the user to know what they've entered?

Comment: Try keyup event instead of keypress.

Comment: Actually, we use RFID tags and the sensor will input the ID into the input field, so the user doesn't have to see the field.

Comment: So why you cannot use input type hidden?

Comment: style="display:none;" ?

Comment: I have already tried all the above three solutions, but none of them works.

Comment: Many CSS possibilities here. text-indent:-9999em; visibility:hidden... They should allow you to enter content. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c42p1ah3/1/

Comment: Are you just trying to capture any keypress while the person is on the page?  Instead of using the input field you could bind the event to the document and save the value to a global javascript variable.  One problem you will run into is if the input field loses focus it won't fire the event.

Comment: @vyx.ca, `text-indent` does the job. Thanks a lot. But I still wonder why `font-size` has anything to do with the input text?

Comment: @yltang52 I have no clue... it shouldn't... but I tested it and it does exactly what you mentioned!

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. The same thing happens with ordinary Javascript `document.getElementById("abc").value`.

Comment: It's very weird. If you assign something to the value, and then type into the field, `.value` works and returns the concatenated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, you can use CSS styles such as text-indent.
The text will be hidden offscreen and you'll stilll be able to get the value.

```
<input id="abc" type="text" autofocus style="text-indent:-9999em;">
```

I do believe that there are other ways to achieve this... like positioning the input offscreen

```
<input id="abc" type="text" autofocus style="position:absolute; left:-9999em; top:-9999em">
```

but your project seems pretty specific.

Comment: Actually, you need to wrap `<input>` by `<div style='text-indent:-9999em;">`